# After updating content some computers see new version but some old at the same time

Tags: cache, bugs, server

I don't know why. Different browsers, computers and internet providers - some show current version of text on my page and some show old content. Site is [dreamvisa.by](http://dreamvisa.by/). Version of Joomla is `2.5.27`. We found this problem when moved this site to the new hosting (aws, Ubuntu), but at this server we have few sites on Joomla and this problem only with this site. I tried to clear cache at Joomla admin panel - nothing.

Comment: K2 Cache  -> Jommla Cache -> Browsers Cache -> Servers Cache (e.g SuperCacher as in SiteGround) => Static Cache => Dynamic Cache => Memcached -> CDN Cache (CloudFlare)

Comment: Your website loads extremely fast. There must be server cache somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `A-name` for my `example.com` but not for `www.example.com` so with `www` we saw old site.

Answer (score 0):

Some hosting providers such as Siteground offer their own caching system which can be extremely aggressive. I tried it once and had the same issue as you, so firstly, ensure that you are not using the cache provided by your hosting provider, or at least **flush** it after making any changes to your site.

Then, go to your Joomla Global Configuration in the backend and make sure you have disabled:

- Gzip Page Compression
- Cache

Once done, go to:

**Joomla backend** >> **System** (top menu) >> **Clear Cache**

Also, if you're using any 3rd party extensions for caching, such as JCH Optimize, try disabling it to see if you still have issues with the content

Comment: Yes, I thought about this, but at admin panel of my `ec2` I do not see word `cache` at any screen...